# I need to set the value of a global variable and save it even on restarting the app

Tags: java, android

So I'm developing a feature in an app where I have a boolean set to `true` which leads to some action being done. Now, `onClick` of a button will do a few related tasks and also set the boolean to `false`. That's fine and it works great, but once it has been changed to `false`, I want that on restarting the app it is assigned as `false` instead of true. I've tried searching for a while without any luck. Help will be appreciated.

I've only been learning Java and Android app dev for 2 months and now I'm making programs, so kindly bear with me. Maybe some sort of use of Boolean instead of boolean? I haven't got too far though.

```
public class Constants {
  public static boolean VARIABLE = true;
}

public Fragment {
  mSharedPreferencesManager.setFeatureUpdateCheck(Constants.VARIABLE);

  if(mSharedPreferencesManager.getFeatureUpdateCheck())
    chatUpdateNotif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                   
  else
    chatUpdateNotif.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

---

```
@OnClick (R.id.chat_notification_close_button)

public void onClickHideNotification() {
  chatUpdateNotif.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  Constants.VARIABLE = false;
```

Comment: instead of hardcoding it to true, read it in from a properties file. I would also recommend to change the classname: Constants isn't appropriate and might be unclear since it isn't' really a constant

Comment: Look at the documentation on how to store settings: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: @L3g3nj use shared-preferences  for store the state of applications get more detail from here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: @Stultuske the class Constants actually has many different variables already written as used by different activities.. so just for the sake of placing my own variable where it is easily editable etc. i put it in the Constants class.

Comment: ok. the fact alone that it is editable means it should be in another class. Why not add a class 'Properties' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear.If you are trying to save a value in closing the application and getting the value back on restart try using shared preferences.

1.Save the value on click of button

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("YOUR PREF NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("VALUE NAME", true).apply();
```

2.Restore the value from preferences on restring app

```
sharedPref.getBoolean("VALUE NAME", null);
```

**Edit**:If your are not using activity use context to use preference

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR PREF NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Probably copy paste error or something, edited it for him

Comment: oh sorry it was error..I copied that line from  my project code

Comment: haha yes now when i think about it the question was unclear because i was unclear about it myself. if i want to actually EDIT the value ofcourse i should use SharedPreferences as it has the editor to do exactly that.. That didnt click in my head.

Comment: haha okie..I think  your problem is solved now.Use SharedPreferences as singleton class and you can use it in entire application efficiently:)

Answer (score 0):

Use Shared Preferences to save the boolean value when it is changed like this:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        "DataSaved", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("VARIABLE", VARIABLE);
editor.commit();
```

Then in Constant write this:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        "DataSaved", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
VARIABLE = sharedPref.getBoolean("VARIABLE", false);
```

Comment: I think the last line should be `VARIABLE = sharedPref.getBoolean("VARIABLE", true);`

Comment: It's default value and I think it should be false if the value is not set by him

Comment: Look at his code. Initially the variable is true, but after the click is is turned to false, and the variable is stored. When you use false as default value, the variable will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String MY_PREFS_NAME = "sharedPref";
```

This sets the boolean:

```
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("Value", false);
    editor.commit();
```

This gets the boolean:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
textview.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getBoolean("Value", true)));
```

This textview will print out false, because the boolean has been set. If the boolean was not set it would be true (default value).

Comment: I don't think `null` is a valid default value for a boolean, an certainly not the correct default value in this specific case.

Comment: In shared preferences if null is set, you expect null, otherwise you will grab whatever is in the shared preferences, null will work fine, as it will only be null if no value has been set

Comment: boolean is a value type, so `null` is not a valid value for boolean. This won't even compile.

Comment: boolean doesnt but Boolean does have null as a value state. I remember reading something like this yesterday.

Comment: I have just edited the answer L3G3NDj :) Hope this is what you are searching for, if not please let me know!